# What are the fields in Campaign Member Object?

Tags: campaign, campaign-member

I am trying to understand the use of the campaign member field status but stuck in understanding the below fields,  I would like to know its functional meaning.

Details:

Instance Type: **Salesforce Developer instance**

SFDC Object : **Campaign Member**

Campaign Member Field : Status

Field Type : Standard Field
[image]

My question

1. What is the "Responded"  field used for ?
2. What is the Default field used for ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the Default field used for ?

The default value is the one that is automatically chosen: the "default" value. While capturing leads online, for example, the status will be set to the default value. Many fields may have default values, such as text fields, date fields, and picklists.

> What is the "Responded" field used for ?

It's used to indicate that a status value indicates a positive response to the campaign. The default configuration has the values of "Sent" and "Responded." This allows you to run reports to find out interesting information. For example, if 100 emails were sent out, and 28 responses were received, we would know that the conversion rate is 28%. This allows us to evaluate the effectiveness of campaigns. Since you may have many different values, even per campaign, it is important to know what constitutes a response, versus those that are not responses, such as "Not Interested" or "Left Voicemail".

Campaign Member Status is one of the few fields that has an "extra" significance to the selected value, including Lead Status, Opportunity Stage, Case Status, and Contract Status. Each field produces some extra effect that aids in improving performance or signalling a change in the system. This particular field produces additional information on the success or penetration of a marketing campaign.

Answer (score 1):

[The status itself is actually an SObject](http://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_campaignmemberstatus.htm), not a regular picklist hence it has these extra options.

Default is just the default value to use when adding a campaign member record. Responded should be used to identify which status values should be used to indicate that the campaign member responded to the campaign in some way. "Sent" should be used to indicate that something has been sent to the member and should probably not count as responded in this case.

From the docs:

> Choose which values will be counted as “Responded.” Members with
>   “Responded” values are tallied in the Total Responses field on the
>   campaign.

You might find this help page of use: [Customizing Campaign Setup](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=campaigns_setup.htm&language=en_US)

Answer (score 1):

The functional usage of the campaign status is to determine if the target audience responded back after your campaign.

you can set one default value that gets selected as Leads/Contacts are added to your campaign. Now whenever you get a response back from these potential prospects, you can edit the campaign members and set the status accordingly.

Now you may have more than one status corresponding to **responded** like :

1. Called Back via Phone
2. Called Back via Email
3. Registered on Website for Demo

But functionally all the above values means the potential prospect responded back. So once you mark status related to responded the fiels : **Responded, Last Responded Date, and Last Modified.** are update automatically.